# php cURL: i want to send user ip address like a data to save it in an other server

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I want to send some data including the visitors ip adress to an other server where it gonna be saved in a txt file, it worked perfectly exept the user ip address, i always find that the ip of the seconde server who is saved not the users ip address.
So in the frist server i used this code :

```
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $arra['ip'] = $ip;
    $ch = curl_init("http://site1.com/script1.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arra);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Forwarded-For: $ip"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
```

And in the seconde server (script1.php) i user this code :

```
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$u = "http://www.geoiptool.com/?IP='$ip'";
$file = fopen("./visitors.txt","+a");
fwrite($file,$message);
fclose($file);
```

PS: I have already did that before, i just dont know what the problem this time.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sending a request from the first server to the second and capturing the IP at `X-Forwarded-For`.

You should extract the `X-Forwarded-For` header in the `script1.php`